# Should I use unix or windows line endings in plain text email?

Tags: email

I am implementing a program that sends automated emails with `Content-Type: text/plain`.

Are there any standards for plain text emails that specify whether to use Unix or Windows style line breaks (LF or CRLF)? Do email clients currently or historically expect a certain line ending type?

In my particular case, I'm wondering if I can use mailer templates in Rails with unix line endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails need to use crlf (`\r\n`, i.e., MS DOS / Windows line endings).

From [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-2.3.7) and the newer [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.8):

> [...] message data [is] transmitted in "lines".  Lines consist of zero or more data characters terminated by the sequence ASCII character "CR" (hex value 0D) followed immediately by ASCII character "LF" (hex value 0A).
> Conforming implementations MUST NOT recognize or generate any other
> character or character sequence as a line terminator.

The [Action Mailer](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/actionmailer) documentation does not say anything about line endings, so I'd assume it "fixes" / "adjusts" them under the covers.

Some [tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/test/mail_helper_test.rb#L94) check for crlf when the passed body didn't use crlf.

Comment: In the newer set of RFCs, I think the better place to look with regard to the message body is [RFC 2046 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.1). In any case, your answer is exactly what I was looking for!